# Error: Jump to case label in switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I wrote a program which involves use of switch statements, however on compilation it shows:

> Error: Jump to case label.

Why does it do that?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    int choice;
    std::cin >> choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
      case 1:
        int i=0;
        break;
      case 2: // error here 
    }
}
```

Comment: What code are you trying to compile? What compiler are you using? Have you enclosed each `case` block in braces?

Comment: that's one impressively roundabout error message

Comment: Indeed, you absolutely could jump to the wrong conclusion from this!

Answer (score 648, accepted):

The problem is that variables declared in one `case` are still visible in the subsequent `case`s unless an explicit `{ }` block is used, *but they will not be initialized* because the initialization code belongs to another `case`.

In the following code, if `foo` equals 1, everything is ok, but if it equals 2, we'll accidentally use the `i` variable which does exist but probably contains garbage.

```
switch(foo) {
  case 1:
    int i = 42; // i exists all the way to the end of the switch
    dostuff(i);
    break;
  case 2:
    dostuff(i*2); // i is *also* in scope here, but is not initialized!
}
```

Wrapping the case in an explicit block solves the problem:

```
switch(foo) {
  case 1:
    {
        int i = 42; // i only exists within the { }
        dostuff(i);
        break;
    }
  case 2:
    dostuff(123); // Now you cannot use i accidentally
}
```

### Edit

To further elaborate, `switch` statements are just a particularly fancy kind of a `goto`. Here's an analoguous piece of code exhibiting the same issue but using a `goto` instead of a `switch`:

```
int main() {
    if(rand() % 2) // Toss a coin
        goto end;

    int i = 42;

  end:
    // We either skipped the declaration of i or not,
    // but either way the variable i exists here, because
    // variable scopes are resolved at compile time.
    // Whether the *initialization* code was run, though,
    // depends on whether rand returned 0 or 1.
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: See this fixed LLVM bug report for other explanations: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7789

Comment: Is `goto` good coding practice in this situation?

Answer (score 108):

Declaration of new variables in case statements is what causing problems. Enclosing all `case` statements in `{}` will limit the scope of newly declared variables to the currently executing case which solves the problem.

```
switch(choice)
{
    case 1: {
       // .......
    }break;
    case 2: {
       // .......
    }break;
    case 3: {
       // .......
    }break;
}
```

Comment: cleaner fix instruction

Comment: Will there be any problem if I put the break statement inside the curly braces?

Comment: I always add braces, all sorts of weird scoping problems can happen if you do not. @VishalSharma its fine to have the break statement inside the braces

Comment: I had never thought to such a simple solution, thank you! +1

Answer (score 19):

**C++11 standard on jumping over some initializations**

[JohannesD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685578/895245) gave an explanation, now for the standards.

The [C++11 N3337 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 6.7 "Declaration statement" says:

> 3 It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A
>   program that jumps (87) from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a
>   point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default
>   constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the
>   preceding types and is declared without an initializer (8.5).
>
> 87) The transfer from the condition of a switch statement to a case label is considered a jump in this respect.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>    // ...
>   goto lx;    // ill-formed: jump into scope of a
>   // ...
> ly:
>   X a = 1;
>   // ...
> lx:
>   goto ly;    // OK, jump implies destructor
>               // call for a followed by construction
>               // again immediately following label ly
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

As of GCC 5.2, the error message now says:

> crosses initialization of

**C**

C allows it: [c99 goto past initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821663/c99-goto-past-initialization)

The [C99 N1256 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) Annex I "Common warnings" says:

> 2 A block with initialization of an object that has automatic storage duration is jumped into

Answer (score 17):

[JohannesD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685578/3982001) is correct, but I feel it isn't entirely clear on an aspect of the problem.

The example he gives declares and initializes the variable `i` in case 1, and then tries to use it in case 2. His argument is that if the switch went straight to case 2, `i` would be used without being initialized, and this is why there's a compilation error. At this point, one could think that there would be no problem if variables declared in a case were never used in other cases. For example:

```
switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        int i = 10; // i is never used outside of this case
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        break;
    case 2:
        int j = 20; // j is never used outside of this case
        printf("j = %d\n", j);
        break;
}
```

One could expect this program to compile, since both `i` and `j` are used only inside the cases that declare them. Unfortunately, in C++ it doesn't compile: as [Ciro Santilli 包子露宪 六四事件 法轮功 explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35757358/3982001), we simply can't jump to `case 2:`, because this would skip the declaration with initialization of `i`, and even though `case 2` doesn't use `i` at all, this is still forbidden in C++.

Interestingly, with some adjustments (an `#ifdef` to `#include` the appropriate header, and a semicolon after the labels, because [labels can only be followed by statements, and declarations do not count as statements in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18496437/3982001)), this program *does* compile as C:

```
// Disable warning issued by MSVC about scanf being deprecated
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdio>
#else
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

int main() {

    int choice;
    printf("Please enter 1 or 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            ;
            int i = 10; // i is never used outside of this case
            printf("i = %d\n", i);
            break;
        case 2:
            ;
            int j = 20; // j is never used outside of this case
            printf("j = %d\n", j);
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks to an online compiler like http://rextester.com you can quickly try to compile it either as C or C++, using MSVC, GCC or Clang. As C it always works (just remember to set STDIN!), as C++ no compiler accepts it.