# "crosses initialization of variable" only when initialization combined with declaration

Tags: c++, performance, g++, switch-statement

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685471/error-jump-to-case-label) about the "jump to case label" error, but I still have some questions. I'm using g++ 4.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

This code gives an error:

```
int main() {
  int foo = 1;
  switch(foo) {
  case 1:
    int i = 0;
    i++;
    break;
  case 2:
    i++;
    break;
  }
}
```

The error is

```
jump-to-case-label.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
jump-to-case-label.cpp:8:8: error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
jump-to-case-label.cpp:5:9: error:   crosses initialization of ‘int i’
```

However, this code compiles fine,

```
int main() {
  int foo = 1;
  switch(foo) {
  case 1:
    int i;
    i = 0;
    i++;
    break;
  case 2:
    i++;
    break;
  }
}
```

Is the second code any less dangerous than the first? I'm confused as to why g++ allows it.

Secondly, the fix for this problem is to scope the initialized variable. If the initialized variable is a large object, and the switch statement is in a while loop, won't the constructor and destructor be called each time that scope is entered and left, causing a decrease in efficiency? Or will the compiler optimize this away?

Comment: I don't get why that compiles. If you go straight to case 2 your `i` hasn't even been declared!

Comment: (The "secondary" error message seems more relevant to the question.)

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain their downvote?

Comment: @alestanis: Why do you think `i` hasn't been declared? It is clearly defined in the block on the line after the `case 1:` label. The `break` statements **don't** magically split the block into different scopes. It wouldn't make any sense to do so because they can be conditionally executed if the programmer chooses to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jumping past the initialization of an object, even if the object is of type `int`, is always undefined behavior. Note, that the `switch`-statement's statement isn't anything special: It is just a statement and people have [ab-]used this interesting ways, e.g., for [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device). The only thing which is special within the statement is that labels can take the form `default:` and `case <const-integer-expr>:`.

The statement `int i;` is a definition of the variable but no initialization. Thus, no initialization of a variable is by-passed. There is no bigger problem jumping past this definition than there is in the first place. Of course, the value gets assigned when jumping to `case 1:` and not when jumping to `case 2:` but this is no different than what happens in code outside of `switch`-statements if people only define variables.

Comment: @alestanis: Of course, it compiles: the code is well-formed and just results in undefined behavior when jumping to the `case 2:` label. It should spit out a warning, though, if `foo == 2`. Just spotted why it doesn't warn: it doesn't warn because the variable is just defined but not initialized. An initialization would look like `int i = 0;`.

Answer (score 2):

At first, compiler decides how it will open `switch` to assembly code. May be `if` or may be table as `goto`. Also, if you write variable initialization together declaration, compiler says you that this is `error`. In another cases it will be `warning` (compiler warns you, but does not resist you). So, you can protect yourself. Just it tunes compiler options, where `warnings` it will be `errors`.
And to work correctly with variables in the `switch`, you must specify their scope. For example:

```
switch(i)
{
case 1:
{
  int j = 0;
}
break;
}
```

PS. For c++, switch is hell.

From C++11:

> **C.1.5 Clause 6: statements**
>
> 6.4.2, 6.6.4 (switch and goto statements)
>
> **Change:** It is now invalid to jump past a declaration with explicit or implicit initializer (except across entire block not entered)
>
> **Rationale:** Constructors used in initializers may allocate resources which need to be de-allocated upon leaving the block.
>   Allowing jump past initializers would require  complicated run-time
>   determination of allocation. Furthermore, any use of the uninitialized
>   object could be a disaster. With this simple compile-time rule, C++
>   assures that if an initialized variable is in scope, then it has
>   assuredly been initialized.
>
> **Effect on original feature:** Deletion of semantically well-defined feature.

From gcc diagnostic pragmas:

> **6.57.10 Diagnostic Pragmas** [Diagnostic Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)
>
> GCC allows the user to selectively enable or disable certain types of
>   diagnostics, and change the kind of the diagnostic. For example, a
>   project's policy might  require that all sources compile with -Werror
>   but certain files might have  exceptions allowing specific types of
>   warnings. Or, a project might selectively  enable diagnostics and
>   treat them as errors depending on which preprocessor macros are
>   defined.

**PSS.** Compiler knows that into the chunk of code your variable uninitialized. Whatever it been `static C/C++ analysis` (For example, for free `cppcheck`) show you problem place.

Comment: Of course, what do you think of Martin Fowler and polymorphism?

Comment: I think splitting logic across 20 classes each with a private method to avoid one switch statement will keep me employed a long time fixing their code after they're fired.

Comment: I talked about the abuse switches'.

Answer (score 1):

Turning on warnings (-Wall) in the second case gives:

```
foo.cpp:15:8: warning: 'i' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Jumping past initialization is an error, but the compiler doesn't try to outguess you on uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a variable inside switch causes this error. This happens due to a permission issue. Try initializing variable outside the switch and assign values inside switch.

Same issue applies to C++ threads.