# How to have the ctime library read anywhere inside a switch

Tags: c++

I am currently doing a supermarket management project for my uni, and one of the criteria is to have the sales timestamped with the system time when they are made. I am using the ctime library with the tm struct, and declaring it with

`time_t now = time(0);
 tm *ltm = localtime(&now);`

at the beggining of the main(), to read the system time from that moment when the variable is declared.

Problem is, if I try to put it inside the switch I'm using it gives me cross initialization error (example and error below). And as I have it on the very beginning of the program, if I let it idle for a few minutes and do a sale, the saved hour will be outdated, which I don't want. Does anyone know how to put this working inside a switch, or a workaround for it? Searched all over google but all I could find was how to define it. Thank you!

Example of intended behaviour:

`#include <ctime>
int main(){
    *variables*
    //----------------------
    switch(menu1){
        case 1:
            *case code*
        break;
        case 2:
            time_t now = time(0);
            tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
            *case code*
        break;
        case 3:
            *case code*
        break;
        default:
            *case code*
        break
    }
    return;
}`

Error im having with this implementation (it also seems to give me an error to every case below where it is implemented):
[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7er1.png)

Comment: best to post the full code and actual error message. there is no reason not being able to get current time within a switch statement, so likely something specific to your code.

Comment: Just updated it, was a little confusing to make it clear because the code itself is really big, tried to put the essential, and also put a picture with the error messages it gives me, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

So, after taking a look at your errors, I found that someone had a similar problem in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685471/error-jump-to-case-label). I'd guess that you have some kind of similar error (I can't tell because you've hidden the content of the cases, sorry). As a result, you could fix your error by scoping your cases inside brackets so you eliminate the chance of using uninitialized variables.

For example:

This snippet won't work due to a redefinition of `i`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int foo = 1;
    switch(foo) {
      case 1:
        int i = 42;
        std::cout << i << '\n';
        break;
      case 2:
        int i = 33; // redefinition of i so the snippet doesn't compile
        std::cout << i * 2 << '\n';
    }
}
```

This can be fixed by simply adding brackets so `i` goes out of scope before you redefine it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int foo = 1;
    switch(foo) {
      case 1: {
        int i = 42;
        std::cout << i << '\n';
        break;
      }
      case 2: {
        // i now can be defined since the previous one is out of scope
        int i = 33;
        std::cout << i * 2 << '\n';
      }
    }
}
```

Hopefully, that makes sense, feel free to correct or clarify with me (I'm pretty new to this)

Answer (score 0):

You can also separate such utilities into functions. Below is a basic date to string function which works in switch.

Better still, put in it's own header and you can re-use outside of the main cpp file.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

std::string now_string() {
 auto timenow = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

return ctime(&timenow);
};

int main(){

int menu1;
std::cin >> menu1;

switch(menu1){
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << now_string() << std::endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return 0;
}
```