# Switch case with char doesn't work with warning: jump to case label [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am currently programming a small GUI framework for an arduino with a small touch screen attachted to it. I need a number pad, that updates one of my other elements on the screen. I have a method that determines where on the number pad the user clicked and returns an char to indicate the result.
Then I want to  change the value or the state of the number pad accordingly.

However, my switch seems broken. The code gets me some warnings by VS Code underlining the first statement after the `case 'a'`, `case 'r'`, `case 'n'`, `default`. It says `jump to case label [-fpermissive]`. [I looked for this warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685471/error-jump-to-case-label-in-switch-statement), but I couldn't find how this warning applies to my switch case. I do not reuse any of my variables, so why am I getting a warning?

```cpp
void SGNumberPad::activated(SGPosition2D position)
{
    Serial.println("numpad click");
    delay(100);
    char clicked = clickedType(position);
    Serial.println(clicked);
    switch (clicked) {
        case 'd':
            int valueSoFar = framedTripleEntry->getCenterValue();
            int newVal = valueSoFar / 10;
            framedTripleEntry->updateCenterValue(newVal);
            break;
        case 'a':
            this->currentlyAdding = !this->currentlyAdding;

            renderAddButton();

            break;
        case 'r':
            this->currentlySubtracting = !this->currentlySubtracting;

            renderSubButton();

            break;
        case 'n':
            Serial.println("Started with number");
            int number = clickedNumber(position);
            Serial.println("number: " + String(number));
            int newValue;
            if (currentlyAdding) {
                newValue = framedTripleEntry->getCenterValue() + number;
            } else if (currentlySubtracting) {
                newValue = framedTripleEntry->getCenterValue() - number;
            } else {
                newValue = framedTripleEntry->getCenterValue() * 10 + number;
            }
            Serial.println("new VAlue: " + String(number));
            framedTripleEntry->updateCenterValue(newValue);
            break;
        default:
            Serial.println("The clicked type was unexpected: " + clicked);
            return;
    }
}
```

However, the code compiles and also runs. When clicking the elements, the position is correctly attributed to the four code characters. However, only if `d` is pressed´, the underlying code is actually executed, if for example `n` is returned, nothing further happens:

```
numpad click
x: 60
y: 75
Pressed numberbutton button
n
//Here should be more output, at least "Started with number"

numpad click
x: 80
y: 165
Pressed remove button
d
```

How can I get my switch to work correctly

Comment: Variable declarations require a scope block (`{}`) there. I am pretty sure we have a dupe for that.

Comment: It is mentioned briefly in the top answer to the linked question, however they do not explicitly state that the scope block is absolutely required. Also I do not understand why the code then fails on the other parts, I do not use any of the variables from the previous blocks...

Comment: It's more or less UB as you present it.

Comment: Ah, okay... That makes sense. I fixed it by adding the scope block, but I still find it curious that even temporary variables cause this kind of issue...

Comment: You do use `newVal` under `case 'n'` that was declared under `case 'd'`. Perhaps you meant to use `newValue` there. Adding explicit scopes would catch such typos, if nothing else.

Comment: Even after correcting that the code is still broken without the scope block... I will probably just use them from now on in my switch case statements.