# Freeing C pointers declared in the middle of a block (seeking documentation on this)

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, declaration

Where is this behaviour documented (if it is at all)?

When you declare a pointer in C in the middle of a block, it will probably be in a wrong state (pointing to unusable memory) and you cannot use the standard `if (a) free(a)` for freeing it.

The simplest program that comes to mind is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc > 1) goto END;
    char *a = NULL;
    a = calloc(1,1);
END:
    if(a) free(a);
}
```

Run the program without parameters and it works OK, if you run it with at least one parameter, it will probably break as follows:
suprisingly (to me), if you compile it with clang, it may work (on my OS X it does, but on a NetBSD it does not). If you do with gcc, it always returns a

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5fc01052: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Notice that the same program with the declaration at the head of the block is correct.

**Edit**: Notice that the question is about *documentation*. I realize doing what I describe is unsafe but I have found no place where it is explicitly shown.

Comment: `goto`s mustn't jump across declarations, I believe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "pattern"

```
if(a) free(a);
```

is certainly *not* standard, or at least it shouldn't be. It's *safe* to pass `NULL` to `free()`, so the `if` adds *nothing*.

I would expect the value of `a` to be undefined (not likely to be `NULL`) if you jump past the initialization, which makes perfect sense to me. This is really hairy code, don't do this.

It could be argued that the existance of the `goto` and label imply a scope that isn't implemented, and there's no reason at all that the `free(a);` statement is after the label (outside the "invisible" scope where `a` is defined).

Comment: Thanks about the if(NULL), you are right. The 'Don't do this' is what bothers me... I would gladly goto the end of a function to free() any allocated pointers. What I did not know (I can see it nowhere, which is my question) is that those pointers are in a wrong state, not NULL. So the place of the declaration is quite relevant for pointers.

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" about it, you're simply doing something ill-advised. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821663/c99-goto-past-initialization) about pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Great. Sorry you had to do my own homework but I could not come up with the precise wording. Done.