# Skip variable declaration using goto?

Tags: c, arrays, goto, variable-declaration

I am reading *C Programming - A Modern Approach* by K.N.King to learn the C programming language and it was noted that `goto` statements must not skip variable-length array declarations.

But now the question is: Why are `goto` jumps allowed to skip fixed-length array declarations and ordinary declarations? And more precisely, what is the behavior of examples like these, according to the C99 standard? When I tested these cases it seemed like the declarations were actually not jumped over, but is that correct? Are the variables whose declarations might have been jumped over safe to use?

**1.**

```
goto later;
int a = 4;
later:
printf("%d", a);
```

**2.**

```
goto later;
int a;
later:
a = 4;
printf("%d", a);
```

**3.**

```
goto later;
int a[4];
a[0] = 1;
later:
a[1] = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++)
  printf("%d\n", a[i]);
```

Comment: @Mints97 Ah, so if statements have their own blocks even without compound statements? I assume that is the answer then :) too bad I can't accept comments

Comment: what do you mean by that? what do if statements have to do with this? And blocks and compound statements are more or less the same, IIRC

Comment: @Mints97 I mean conditionally declared variables are not moved to the beginning of the entire function but only to the beginning of the conditional "block" they exist in right? So an if statement without compound statement would represent such a block too. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No. A block is a block, alias a compound statement, starts with {, ends with }. My comment about declarations being "moved to the beginning of the block where they're declared" was quite unclear, so I deleted the comment and am trying to elaborate on the subject with an answer. And yes, "conditional declaration" is not a thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c99 goto past initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821663/c99-goto-past-initialization)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm in the mood for explaining this without gory memory-layout details (believe me, they get *very* gory when VLAs are used; see @Ulfalizer's answer for details).

So, originally, in C89, it was mandatory to declare all variables at the start of a block, like this:

```
{
    int a = 1;
    a++;
    /* ... */
}
```

This directly implies a very important thing: one block == one unchanging set of variable declarations.

C99 changed this. In it, you can declare variables in any part of the block, but declaration statements are still different from regular statements.

In fact, to understand this, you can imagine that all variable declarations are implicitly moved to the start of the block where they are declared and made unavailable for all statements that preceed them.

That is simply because *the one block == one set of declarations* rule still holds.

That is why you cannot "jump over a declaration". The declared variable would still exist.

The problem is initialization. It doesn't get "moved" anywhere. So, technically, for your case, the following programs could be considered equivalent:

```
goto later;
int a = 100;
later:
printf("%d", a);
```

and

```
int a;
goto later;
a = 100;
later:
printf("%d", a);
```

As you can see, the declaration is still there, what is being skipped is initialization.

The reason this doesn't work with VLAs is that they're different. In short, it's because this is valid:

```
int size = 7;
int test[size];
```

The declarations of VLAs will, unlike all other declarations, behave differently in different parts of the block where they are declared. In fact, a VLA might have entirely different memory layouts depending on where it is declared. You just can't "move" it outside of the place you just jumped over.

You may ask, "all right, then why not make it so that the declaration would be unaffected by the `goto`"? Well, you'd still get cases like this:

```
goto later;
int size = 7;
int test[size];
later:
```

What do you actually expect this to do?..

So, prohibiting jumping over VLA declarations is there for a reason - it is the most logical decision for dealing with cases like the above by simply prohibiting them altogether.

Comment: Even in C89/C90, it was legal to jump into a block: `goto LABEL; { int n = 42; LABEL: printf("%d\n", n); }`

Comment: @KeithThompson: woah, thanks! I completely forgot that one =) I'll edit the answer right away!

Comment: A amazing/terrifying example of what @KeithThompson mentions is known as [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).  It uses switch labels to jump into the middle of a while loop.

Comment: "*but declaration statements are still different from regular statements*" -- A terminology quibble. In C, declarations are not statements. (Just to add to the confusion, in C++ the word "statements" includes both what C calls "statements" and "declarations".)

Answer (score 7):

The reason you're not allowed to skip over the declaration of a variable-length array (VLA) is that it would get messy with the way VLAs are commonly implemented, and would complicate the semantics of the language.

The way VLAs are likely to implemented in practice is by decrementing (or incrementing, on architectures where the stack grows upwards) the stack pointer by a dynamic (calculated at runtime) amount to make room for the VLA on the stack. This happens at the point where the VLA is declared (conceptually at least, ignoring optimizations). This is needed so that later stack operations (e.g., pushing arguments to the stack for a function call) do not step on the VLA's memory.

For VLAs nested in blocks, the stack pointer would commonly be restored at the end of the block containing the VLA. If a `goto` was allowed to jump into such a block and past the declaration of a VLA, then the code to restore the stack pointer would run without the corresponding initialization code having been run, which would likely cause problems. For example, the stack pointer might be incremented by the size of the VLA even though it was never decremented, which would, among other things, make the return address that was pushed when the function containing the VLA was called appear in the wrong place relative to the stack pointer.

It's also messy from a pure language semantics perspective. If you're allowed to skip over the declaration, then what would the size of the array be? What should `sizeof` return? What does it mean to access it?

For the non-VLA cases, you would simply skip the value initialization (if any), which doesn't necessarily cause problems in and of itself. If you jump over a non-VLA definition like `int x;`, then storage will still be reserved for the variable `x` as well. VLAs are different in that their size is calculated at runtime, which complicates things.

As a side note, one of the motivations for allowing variables to be declared anywhere within a block in C99 (C89 requires declarations to be at the beginning of the block, though at least GCC allows them within the block as an extension) was to support VLAs. Being able to perform calculations earlier in the block before declaring the size of the VLA is handy.

For somewhat related reasons, C++ does not allow `goto`s to skip over object declarations (or initializations for plain old data types, e.g. `int`). This is because it would be unsafe to jump over the code that calls the constructor but still run the destructor at the end of the block.

Answer (score 4):

Using a `goto` to jump over the declaration of a variable is almost certainly a really bad idea, but it's perfectly legal.

C makes a distinction between the *lifetime* of a variable and its *scope*.

For a variable declared without the `static` keyword inside a function, its scope (the region of program text in which its name is visible) extends from the definition to the end of the nearest enclosing block. Its lifetime (storage duration) begins on entry to the block and ends on exit from the block. If it has an initializer, it's executed when (and if) the definition is reached.

For example:

```
{  /* the lifetime of x and y starts here; memory is allocated for both */
    int x = 10; /* the name x is visible from here to the "}" */
    int y = 20; /* the name y is visible from here to the "}" */
    int vla[y]; /* vla is visible, and its lifetime begins here */
    /* ... */
}
```

For variable length arrays (VLAs), the visibility of the identifier is the same, but the lifetime of the object begins at the definition. Why? Because the length of the array is not necessarily known prior to that point. In the example, it's not possible to allocate memory for `vla` at the beginning of the block, because we don't yet know the value of `y`.

A `goto` that skips over an object definition bypasses any initializer for that object, but memory is still allocated for it. If the `goto` jumps into a block, memory is allocated as the block is entered. If it doesn't (if both the `goto` and the target label are at the same level in the same block), then the object will already have been allocated.

```
...
goto LABEL;
{
    int x = 10;
    LABEL: printf("x = %d\n", x);
}
```

When the `printf` statement is executed, `x` exists and its name is visible, but its initialization has been bypassed, so it has an indeterminate value.

The language forbids a `goto` that skips the definition of a variable-length array. If it were permitted, it would skip the allocation of memory for the object, and any attempt to reference it would cause undefined behavior.

`goto` statements [do have their uses](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133523/33478). Using them to skip over declarations, though it's permitted by the language, is not one of them.

Comment: this is interesting, but I wonder can we skip an array with a fix size at compile time with a goto statement?

Comment: @FitriHalim Yes, that's allowed (but a bad idea). Memory for a fixed-size array, as for anything other than VLAs, is allocated on entry to the enclosing block. A `goto` that skips the declaration will bypass any initialization, but it can't bypass the allocation of memory for the object itself.