# (iOS) Jump bypasses initialization of retaining variable when using goto

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, goto

I got this compiler error when using goto in my ARC iOS project.

> Cannot jump from this goto statement to its label. Jump bypasses
>   initialization of retaining variable

I know goto is bad in general but ... please just tell me how to fix it. The codes are like following,

```
//some process
NSArray *current = ... ;
if (current.count ==0) goto cleanup;
//proceed to next
if (processed failed) goto cleanup;
//further process

cleanup:
//clean up codes
```

Comment: Looks like you initialised a local variable in for(;;) statement and then you left those scope by goto: and ARC is no longer able to release the variable.

Comment: "goto" in obj-c. the second time I'm seeing it, first was in a book.

Comment: can you post some more code?

Comment: Solved! See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out! Actually the warning said it clearly, "Jump **bypasses initialization** of retaining variable" so in the section next

> //In proceed to next section I declare & init some object!

My codes/problem is basically the same as [c99 goto past initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821663/c99-goto-past-initialization)

The solution is simple, just added a {} block to it, as here mentioned [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)

For those who are wondering why I still need goto, I think this explained it [Is it ever advantageous to use 'goto' in a language that supports loops and functions? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451/is-it-ever-advantageous-to-use-goto-in-a-language-that-supports-loops-and-func/24476#24476)  , especially "Cleanly exiting a function", check here for an example
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/04/27/using-goto-for-error-handling-in-c

Without goto mainline code is deep inside the nested conditions (Of course we can also introduce a helper function to deal with it).